# Socket.IO "multiple tenants" for dynamic namespace per tenant

Tags: socket.io

Can someone explain "tenant" here? I don't think it's a user. Feel more like some kind of a "use".

Quote from socket.io

> your application has multiple tenants so you want to dynamically
> create one namespace per tenant

If it is just to group sockets under a namespace for the sake of flexibility, why call it tenant? Why not just called it "dynamic custom namespace"? I feel I missed something very critical here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the use of tenant here implies that the application is sectioned into multiple parts. Generally speaking, in a multi tenant application there can be one application server that interacts with multiple databases (eg: one database per company on your app) and a user can fall into one or many of these companies.

I was also confused by the wording which prompted me to find this question in my research.

For the purposes of this tenant use case, the tenant will be unique groups that the users on the application fall into eg companies that they belong to inside your app.